# strange parse error when including a loop template within another template

Tags: loop, errors, get-template-part, include

I have a loop template called `loop-event-details.php` where I have code to display each event.

My main page template is called `events-page.php`. I use the following code to include the loop template:

```
get_template_part( 'loop', 'event-details' );
```

I have also trying this code:

```
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/loop-event-details.php');
```

However, when viewing a page it always complains about parsing error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in /<my_templatepath>/loop-event-details.php on line 1
```

The `loop` isn't on line 1, but line 15. The code in the `loop` file is correct, because when I copy and paste all the code from the `loop` file into the `page` file it all works. As soon as I try to include it with either contract (`get_template_part()` or `include()`) it doesn't work and always complains about line 1.

Any tips and help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks,
Dasha

WP 3.1.0

PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny9

Comment: Maybe some stray whitespace at the end of `loop-event-details.php`?

Comment: +1 @t31os. Try to just write it piece per piece again into a new file and see what happens.

Comment: @kaiser did that, still the same :S soo confusing! Btw, I've got the same set up on my local machine (PHP 5.3.1) and it works alright. But displays that error on the online dev site with PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny9

Comment: Stupid, but give it a try: a) Really **Write** it (no copy/paste) into a new file b) check if you got utf-8 bom and not any other char-set.

Comment: Try including a completely empty *loop-event-details.php* using *get_template_part()*, and see if you still get the error?

Comment: +1 Chip, including an empty copy would help highlight whether it's a specific problem with that file or a more general inclusion problem.

Comment: @Chip Bennett, @t31os If I include empty _loop-event-details.php_ or even with a simple `echo` it does work. It must be a file then. I will try writing it again, not copying/pasting. Will let you know. Thanks guys :)

Comment: @t31os, @kaiser, @Chip Bennett Ok, I've created a new file, specified the encoding as "UTF-8" and retyped everything by hand - no copy/paste. Works great! Thanks guys! :)

Comment: P.S. how do I mark this question as resolved if there are no answeres?

Comment: @DashaLuna - Great news, happy to hear you were able to solve the problem... :)

Comment: @DashaLuna: You can write an answer yourself and accept it. You won't get a reputation increase, but it will mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new file, specified the encoding as "UTF-8" and retyped everything by hand - no copy/paste from the old file. Took a while, but all works now. It must have been some encoding errors playing up.

Thanks to everyone who helped: @t31os, @kaiser, @Chip Bennett